# Personalized PageRank and Random Walks

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, dynamical-systems, random-walk, page-rank

I have two questions, each regarding personalized PageRank as provided in a paper I'm reading ("Approximate Personalized PageRank on Dynamic Graphs" by Zhang, Lofgren and Goel; see [1](https://www.kdd.org/kdd2016/papers/files/rfp1146-zhangA.pdf), [2](https://doi.org/10.1145/2939672.2939804), or [3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07796)).

---

**First Question:**

The authors give the equation for the personalized PageRank vector $\pi_s$ of a source node $s$:

$$\pi_s = \alpha e_s + (1-\alpha) R \pi_s$$

where $\alpha$ is the teleport probability, $e_s$ is the indicator vector for $s$, and $R$ is the random walk matrix. Would a correct formulation of the personalized PageRank *matrix* $\pi$ then be

$$\pi = \alpha I + (1-\alpha) R  \pi$$

where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix and $\pi_{s, t}$ is the probability that a random walk from $s$ stops at $t$ given teleport probability $\alpha$? If so, doesn't this not make any sense for $\alpha = 0$ since then we're left with $\pi = R \pi$ and so $R = I$, which is false? What's the correct matrix formulation, or is $a=0$ just not allowed?

---

**Second Question:**

Is there any insight on what happens when using powers of $R$? I understand that $R^k_{i, j}$ is the probability of node $i$ landing on node $j$ within $k$ hops. Does this mean using $R^k$ in the personalized PageRank equation corresponds to computing the probability of going from node $s$ to $t$ within $k$ hops with teleport probability $\alpha$?

Comment: Please provide a full reference.  Links to PDF files are quite useless once the links are broken.